# Can you add a line break above all <h2> tags?

Tags: line-breaks

Here's how my text looks like in my text editor - https://prnt.sc/FPDv_zIwQz2R
Here's how the web page appears when previewed - https://prnt.sc/fvKit11H3Xr4

As you can see, there's no break above the .

Of course I can manually add breaks but it would be really tedious and painstaking. Is there a code to include in functions.php or elsewhere that would add a line break above all  tags?

Thank you!

Comment: The spacing here would be determined by the CSS of your theme. In most stylesheets paragraphs have a bottom margin or headings have a top margin.

Answer (score 0):

You might set the line height of the h2 in the custom css like this

```
h2
{
    line-height: 5px !important
}
```

but this is just a workaround.